# How to execute a Javascript submit form function in scrapy function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to "scrapy", i am scrapping a website and in that i had some anchor tags which consists of href attributes with java script SubmitForm functions. When i clicked that javascript function a page is opening from which i need to fetch data.I used Xpath and found href for particular anchor tags but unable to execute that href attribute that contains javascript function. Can anyone tell me how to execute javascript Submit functions of anchor tags in scrapy python.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648644/executing-javascript-submit-form-functions-using-scrapy-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy can not excute javascript. Selenium can: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html