# Executing Javascript Submit form functions using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scrapping a site using scrapy framework and having trouble clicking on a javascript link for opening another page.

I can identify the code on the page as:

```
<a class="Page" alt="Click to view job description" title="Click to view job description" href="javascript:sysSubmitForm('frmSR1');">Accountant&nbsp;</a>
```

can any one suggest me how to execute that javascript in scaroy and get another page through i can fetch data from that page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Checkout the below snipped on how to use scrapy with selenium. Crawling will be slower as you aren't just downloading the html but you will get full access to the DOM.

Note: I have copy-pasted this snippet as the links previously provided no longer work.

```
# Snippet imported from snippets.scrapy.org (which no longer works)

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request

from selenium import selenium

class SeleniumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "SeleniumSpider"
    start_urls = ["http://www.domain.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\.html', )),
        callback='parse_page',follow=True),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.domain.com")
        self.selenium.start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        print self.verificationErrors
        CrawlSpider.__del__(self)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = Item()

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #Do some XPath selection with Scrapy
        hxs.select('//div').extract()

        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open(response.url)

        #Wait for javscript to load in Selenium
        time.sleep(2.5)

        #Do some crawling of javascript created content with Selenium
        sel.get_text("//div")
        yield item
```

Comment: Neither link is helpful any more, which is why stackoverflow asks that you at least summarize pages here.  Can you say some more, or locate the original answers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check out a fairly huge, functional code base which uses scrapy and selenium, check out https://github.com/nicodjimenez/bus_catchers.  Here is a simpler example.

```
# stripped down BoltBus script 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Response 
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
import time

# set dates, origin, destination 
cityOrigin="Baltimore"
cityDeparture="New York"
day_array=[0]
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# we are going the day of the days of the month from 15,16,...,25
# there is a discrepancy between the index of the calendar days and the day itself: for example day[10] may correspond to Feb 7th
for day in day_array:

    # Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    browser.get("http://www.boltbus.com")

    # click on "region" tab
    elem_0=browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphM_forwardRouteUC_lstRegion_textBox")
    elem_0.click()
    time.sleep(5) 

    # select Northeast
    elem_1=browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Northeast")
    elem_1.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # click on origin city
    elem_2=browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphM_forwardRouteUC_lstOrigin_textBox")
    elem_2.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # select origin city
    elem_3=browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(cityOrigin)
    elem_3.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # click on destination city 
    elem_4=browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphM_forwardRouteUC_lstDestination_textBox")
    elem_4.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # select destination city 
    elem_5=browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(cityDeparture)
    elem_5.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    # click on travel date
    travel_date_elem=browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphM_forwardRouteUC_imageE")
    travel_date_elem.click()    

    # gets day rows of table
    date_rows=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("daysrow") 

    # select actual day (use variable day)
    # NOTE: you must make sure these day elements are "clickable"
    days=date_rows[0].find_elements_by_xpath("..//td")
    days[day].click()
    time.sleep(3) 

    # retrieve actual departure date from browser
    depart_date_elem=browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphM_forwardRouteUC_txtDepartureDate")
    depart_date=str(depart_date_elem.get_attribute("value"))

    # PARSE TABLE

    # convert html to "nice format"
    text_html=browser.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    html_str=str(text_html)

    # this is a hack that initiates a "TextResponse" object (taken from the Scrapy module)
    resp_for_scrapy=TextResponse('none',200,{},html_str,[],None)

    # takes a "TextResponse" object and feeds it to a scrapy function which will convert the raw HTML to a XPath document tree
    hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(resp_for_scrapy)

    # the | sign means "or"
    table_rows=hxs.select('//tr[@class="fareviewrow"] | //tr[@class="fareviewaltrow"]')
    row_ct=len(table_rows)

    for x in xrange(row_ct):

        cur_node_elements=table_rows[x]
        travel_price=cur_node_elements.select('.//td[@class="faresColumn0"]/text()').re("\d{1,3}\.\d\d")

        # I use a mixture of xpath selectors to get me to the right location in the document, and regular expressions to get the exact data

        # actual digits of time 
        depart_time_num=cur_node_elements.select('.//td[@class="faresColumn1"]/text()').re("\d{1,2}\:\d\d")

        # AM or PM (time signature)
        depart_time_sig=cur_node_elements.select('.//td[@class="faresColumn1"]/text()').re("[AP][M]")

        # actual digits of time 
        arrive_time_num=cur_node_elements.select('.//td[@class="faresColumn2"]/text()').re("\d{1,2}\:\d\d")

        # AM or PM (time signature)
        arrive_time_sig=cur_node_elements.select('.//td[@class="faresColumn2"]/text()').re("[AP][M]")

        print "Depart date: " + depart_date
        print "Depart time: " + depart_time_num[0] + " " + depart_time_sig[0]   
        print "Arrive time: " + arrive_time_num[0] + " " + arrive_time_sig[0]
        print "Cost: " + "$" + travel_price[0] 
        print "\n"
```

Comment: Hey @nicodjimenez, thanks for your code. I got it to work, except it seems for selecting the dates. I didn't understand when you say "# we are going the day of the days of the month from 15,16,...,25". Also, you note: "you must make sure these day elements are "clickable"." Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, scrappy crawler implemented over urrlib2 and urllib obviously dont work with js. For working with js you can use qt webkit or selenium for example. Or you could find all ajax links on page and see how implemented a data exchange with the server and send response to server api indirectly.