# selenium with scrapy for dynamic page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape product information from a webpage, using scrapy. My to-be-scraped webpage looks like this:

- starts with a product_list page with 10 products
- a click on "next"  button loads the next 10 products (url doesn't change between the two pages)
- i use LinkExtractor to follow each product link into the product page, and get all the information I need

I tried to replicate the next-button-ajax-call but can't get working, so I'm giving selenium a try. I can run selenium's webdriver in a separate script, but I don't know how to integrate with scrapy. Where shall I put the selenium part in my scrapy spider?

My spider is pretty standard, like the following:

```
class ProductSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/shanghai']
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@id="productList"]//dl[@class="t2"]//dt'), callback='parse_product'),
        ]

    def parse_product(self, response):
        self.log("parsing product %s" %response.url, level=INFO)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # actual data follows
```

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714354/scrapy-selenium-requests-twice-for-each-url/50715420#50715420

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It really depends on how do you need to scrape the site and how and what data do you want to get.

Here's an example how you can follow pagination on ebay using `Scrapy`+`Selenium`:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=books&_osacat=0&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.Xpython&_nkw=python&_sacat=0&_from=R40']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="pagn-next"]/a')

            try:
                next.click()

                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

Here are some examples of "selenium spiders":

- [Executing Javascript Submit form functions using scrapy in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648644/executing-javascript-submit-form-functions-using-scrapy-in-python)
- https://gist.github.com/cheekybastard/4944914
- https://gist.github.com/irfani/1045108
- http://snipplr.com/view/66998/

---

There is also an alternative to having to use `Selenium` with `Scrapy`. In some cases, using [`ScrapyJS` middleware](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) is enough to handle the dynamic parts of a page. Sample real-world usage:

- [Scraping dynamic content using python-Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy)

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually my biggest problem is in the part after next.click(). Every time I get a new page, but can I still use a LinkExtractor to extract all the product urls then use a callback to parse them?

Comment: Is there a way to re-use the reponse that has already been grabbed by scrapy instead of using `self.driver.get(response.url)` ?

Comment: @Z.Lin is the problem you've described still present? If you've solved it, could you share the solution? Thanks. Also, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: @Ethereal I'm afraid this is the overhead you get here. Good point though.

Comment: To install on ubuntu: `sudo pip install selenium`. To hide the browser window: [install & example on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8910326/2227298).

Comment: hi @alecxe..I had a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420078/scrapy-with-selenium-for-a-webpage-requiring-authentication which is something right up your alley..if you do get some time,please have a look into it

Comment: If we were to use this code. Wouldn't it be better to just use selenium all the way? I mean scrapy isn't doing anything here

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez this is just an example with the selenium part in the scrapy spider. After selenium is done, usually the `self.driver.page_source` is passed in to a Selector instance for Scrapy to parse the HTML, form the item instances, pass them to pipelines etc. Or, selenium cookies can be parsed and passed to Scrapy to make additional requests. But, if you don't need the power of the scrapy framework architecture, then, sure, you can use just selenium - it is itself quite powerful in locating the elements.

Comment: @alecxe yeah while I get the concept. Im still confused at the part where you extract the page source using selenium and pass the elements you want to be scraped to scrapy. for example. There is a load more button clicking it will show more items but and you extract the xpath for those items. now how do you pass those xpaths to scrapy? because only the items shown when you first requested the page will be parsed by scrappy and not the ones after clicking the load more button with selenium

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez got it, I would load more items until there is no more to add. Then, take the `driver.page_source` and pass it to the `Selector()`..

Comment: ok I got kinda get thank you @alecxe one last question.

using that approach with selenium and loading more items and stuff. Is it possible to use the crawl spider class to extract info from the newly loaded items?

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez this is something I would need additional info and see your code. Could you create a separate question so that more people can help you? Thanks.

Comment: I would if I could but im banned from asking questions. F*** me.

anyway thanks for the time :D

Comment: Doing it without scrapy with Selenium driver. The condition does not hold true once it navigates to 2nd page. How to keep it clicking?

Comment: @alecxe Using your advice I get "TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'unicode' object" .. I've never seen this before- any help?

Comment: @BenjaminJames this is not related to the answer itself. Try googling or asking a separate question here on SO.

Comment: @alecxe i'm getting the following error (`[4960:6000:0612/235425.186:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2`). can you please tell me what's i'm doing wrong if i show you my script?!?! anybody?

Answer (score 4):

If (url doesn't change between the two pages) then you should add *dont_filter=True* with your scrapy.Request() or scrapy will find this url as a duplicate after processing first page.

If you need to render pages with javascript you should use [scrapy-splash](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash), you can also check this [scrapy middleware](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) which can handle javascript pages using selenium or you can do that by launching any headless browser

But more effective and faster solution is inspect your browser and see what requests are made during submitting a form or triggering a certain event. Try to simulate the same requests as your browser sends. If you can replicate the request(s) correctly you will get the data you need.

Here is an example :

```
class ScrollScraper(Spider):
    name = "scrollingscraper"

    quote_url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page="
    start_urls = [quote_url + "1"]

    def parse(self, response):
        quote_item = QuoteItem()
        print response.body
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        for item in data.get('quotes', []):
            quote_item["author"] = item.get('author', {}).get('name')
            quote_item['quote'] = item.get('text')
            quote_item['tags'] = item.get('tags')
            yield quote_item

        if data['has_next']:
            next_page = data['page'] + 1
            yield Request(self.quote_url + str(next_page))
```

When pagination url is same for every pages & uses POST request then you can use *scrapy.FormRequest()* instead of *scrapy.Request()*, both are same but FormRequest adds a new argument (*formdata=*) to the constructor.

Here is another spider example form this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189862/scrapy-follow-pagination-ajax-request-post):

```
class SpiderClass(scrapy.Spider):
    # spider name and all
    name = 'ajax'
    page_incr = 1
    start_urls = ['http://www.pcguia.pt/category/reviews/#paginated=1']
    pagination_url = 'http://www.pcguia.pt/wp-content/themes/flavor/functions/ajax.php'

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        if self.page_incr > 1:
            json_data = json.loads(response.body)
            sel = Selector(text=json_data.get('content', ''))

        # your code here

        # pagination code starts here
        if sel.xpath('//div[@class="panel-wrapper"]'):
            self.page_incr += 1
            formdata = {
                'sorter': 'recent',
                'location': 'main loop',
                'loop': 'main loop',
                'action': 'sort',
                'view': 'grid',
                'columns': '3',
                'paginated': str(self.page_incr),
                'currentquery[category_name]': 'reviews'
            }
            yield FormRequest(url=self.pagination_url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)
        else:
            return
```