# infinite scroll - python

Tags: python, selenium, infinite-scroll, bing

I am scraping a site using selenium. The site uses infinite scrolling, so I am trying to use selenium to scroll down and get more search results than those served after the first request.

I adapted the following, excellent script:

[crawl site that has infinite scrolling using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702277/crawl-site-that-has-infinite-scrolling-using-python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

driver.get(my_url)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
for i in range(1,100):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(4)
    html_source = driver.page_source
    data = html_source.encode('utf-8')
```

The web browser is opened using the url above. However, I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/IdenSoft/unittest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/xxxx/unittest.py", line 23, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
File C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\xxxx\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-  packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\lib\site     packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

***How should I change the script for it to work?***

Comment: Which version of Firefox you are using?

Comment: Firefox nightly 52.0a1 (2016-10-27)(32-bit)

Comment: Selenium webdriver doesn't support latest version of Firefox. Try downgrading your Firefox browser version to 46 or lower and then give a try. PS: I am using Firefox 32 and it works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

This line have a probem : `driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()`

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
my_url = "https://aparat.com/khaledsss" #you can change this
#Open Browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#Open Url
driver.get(my_url)
#for loop 
for i in range(1,100):
    # * With this line You can skip infinite scroll
    #scroll to Down
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #Wait for 4 secend
    time.sleep(4)
# ... code ...
```