# javascript error: arguments[0].scrollTo is not a function using Selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm receiving the following error when launching my python script with selenium.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollTo is not a function
```

I'm not sure what exactly is going on here - I would give more detail, but here is the program I'm running where this error is coming from.

```
  def scroll_slow(self, scrollable_element, start=0, end=3600, step=100, reverse=False):
        if reverse:
            start, end = end, start
            step = -step

        for i in range(start, end, step):
            self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, {})".format(i), scrollable_element)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 2.6))
```

If you see anything out of place, please help.

I've tried commenting this section out - but it messes up the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can't invoke [`scrollTo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689339/7429447) on any WebElement but on the ***`Window`*** object.

---

### Solution

There can be two approaches:

- Either you [`scrollIntoView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581830/7429447) the element:

  ```
  self.browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", scrollable_element)
  ```
- Or you invoke [`scrollTo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55208153/7429447) on the ***`Window`*** object:

  ```
  self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
  ```