# Why is selenium only iterating 5 times instead of completing the data set

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to scrape data on a dynamic website. after picking the elements I set a for loop to append to a list instead of iterating the whole set of data. it iterates only 5x and stops. what could be the cause of this?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

ser= Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=ser)
driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
print(driver.title)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

song_contents = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'soundList__item')

song_list = []

for option in song_contents:
    search = option.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__username')]/span").text
    search_song = option.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__title')]/span").text
    search_date = option.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//time[contains(@class,'relativeTime')]/span").text
    search_plays = option.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(@class,'sc-ministats-small')]/span").text
   
    option ={
        'Artist': search, 
        'Song_title': search_song, 
        'Date': search_date,
        'Streams': search_plays
    }

    song_list.append(option)

df = pd.DataFrame(song_list)
print(df)


driver.quit()
```

**Output**

```
Stream Juju Bucks music | Listen to songs, albums, playlists for free on SoundCloud
       Artist                              Song_title               Date Streams
0  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
1  Juju Bucks            Tropikana ft. P-Dogg Amazing  Posted 1 year ago      31
2  Juju Bucks              Party Ka Mngani Ft. X-Poll  Posted 1 year ago      31
3  Juju Bucks      Joy Ft. Black Sushi & Gavin Bowden  Posted 1 year ago      31
4  Juju Bucks                      Amazing ft. X-Poll  Posted 1 year ago      31
```

Comment: show us the value of `song_contents`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702277/crawl-site-that-has-infinite-scrolling-using-python Your page has only 5 loaded at the start you could do this to get them all or requests.