# Use scrapy to crawl a property within a block

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl this link:

```
<input class="xxxmail" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="xxx.org">
```

I just need the "xxx.org". How do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [`xpath`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression:

```
//input[@class="xxxmail"]/@value
```

This will get the `value` attribute of an `input` tag with the "xxxmail" `class`.

In the spider, you should first instantiate the [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) and then [`extract()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract) from the `xpath`:

```
sel = Selector(response)
print sel.xpath('//input[@class="xxxmail"]/@value').extract()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your method. It doesn't work. I think the problem is not the xpath, but there is a upper level div shown as style="display: block;"

Comment: @willie cannot say more without seeing the actual webpage u are crawling.

Comment: Hi, it is like this 
<div class="reply_options" style="display: block;">
<ul><li>
<input class="anonemail" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="xx@xxx.org">
</li></ul>
</div>

Comment: @willie can you give a link to the webpage? Also, what error are you getting? Have u replaced `xxxmail` with `anonemail`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I don't get any errors because the crawler can't find that xpath before the button is clicked. I want to crawl this page:

http://newbrunswick.en.craigslist.ca/rvs/4443347993.html

There is a button "contact" only after you click it , you can see the contact's email address which I want to get.

Comment: @willie the data you need is in `div` with `reply_options` class. Try `//div[@class="reply_options"]` xpath.

Comment: Hi, I have attempted all these xpaths, that's why I believe a function to click to button is needed. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @willie you cannot make a UI click action with `Scrapy`. If you think you need to click a button, check [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) tool. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I know. But I haven't find a useful example combining scrapy and selenum.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page

Comment: Hi, I tried those examples but always get this warning:  ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SeleniumSpider.spiders.SeleniumSpider.SeleniumSpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class SeleniumSpider(BaseSpider)

Can you write a simple scheme on how to use selenum in scrapy? Also is it possible If I use CrawlSpider?