# selenium ajax dynamic pagination base spider

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, pagination, scrapy

I am trying to run my Base spider for dynamic pagination but I am not getting success in crawling. I have used selenium ajax dynamic pagination. the url I am using is: http://www.demo.com. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

import re

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from scrapy.selector import Selector

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

from demo.items import demoItem

from selenium import webdriver

def removeUnicodes(strData):

        if(strData):

            #strData = strData.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')

            strData = strData.encode('utf-8').strip() 

            strData = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t]',r' ',strData.strip())

            #print 'Output:',strData

        return strData


class demoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "demourls"

    allowed_domains = ["demo.com"]

    start_urls = ['http://www.demo.com']

     def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        print "*****************************************************"
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        print response.url
        print "______________________________"



        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = sumItem()
        finalurls = []
        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="showMoreCars hide"]/a')

            try:
                next.click()
                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
                item['pageurl'] = response.url
                item['title'] =  removeUnicodes(hxs.xpath('.//h1[@class="page-heading"]/text()').extract()[0])
                urls = hxs.xpath('.//a[@id="linkToDetails"]/@href').extract()
                print '**********************************************2***url*****************************************',urls


                for url in urls:
                    print '---------url-------',url
                finalurls.append(url)          

                item['urls'] = finalurls

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()

        return item
```

my items.py is

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class demoItem(Item):



    page = Field()
    urls = Field()

    pageurl = Field()
    title = Field()
```

when I am trying to crawl it and convert it in json I am getting my json file as:

```
[{"pageurl": "http://www.demo.com", "urls": [], "title": "demo"}]
```

I am not able to crawl all urls  as it is dynamically loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below code will help.

### somespider.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from demo.items import DemoItem
from selenium import webdriver

def removeUnicodes(strData):
        if(strData):
            strData = strData.encode('utf-8').strip() 
            strData = re.sub(r'[\n\r\t]',r' ',strData.strip())
        return strData

class demoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "domainurls"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/used/cars-in-trichy/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = DemoItem()
        finalurls = []
        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="showMoreCars hide"]/a')

            try:
                next.click()
                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
                item['pageurl'] = response.url
                item['title'] =  removeUnicodes(hxs.xpath('.//h1[@class="page-heading"]/text()').extract()[0])
                urls = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@id="linkToDetails"]')

                for url in urls:
                    url = url.get_attribute("href")
                    finalurls.append(removeUnicodes(url))          

                item['urls'] = finalurls

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
        return item
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class DemoItem(Item):
    page = Field()
    urls = Field()
    pageurl = Field()
    title = Field()
```

**Note:**
You need to have selenium rc server running because HTMLUNITWITHJS works with selenium rc only using Python.

**Run your selenium rc server issuing the command** :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
```

**Run your spider using command**:

```
spider crawl domainurls -o someoutput.json
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to press **showMoreCars** button as it will be dynamically pressed after page load. Instead, waiting for some second will be enough.

Apart from you `scrapy` code, selenium is able to capture all `href`s for you. Here is an example of what you need to do in selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/#city=194&kms=0-&year=0-&budget=0-&pn=2")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[@id="linkToDetails"]')
for url in urls:
    print url.get_attribute("href")
driver.close()
```

all you need is to merge this with your scrapy part.

Output:

```
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/renault-pulse-s586981/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/marutisuzuki-ritz-2009-2012-s598266/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/mahindrarenault-logan-2007-2009-s607757/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/marutisuzuki-ritz-2009-2012-s589835/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/hyundai-santro-xing-2003-2008-s605866/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/chevrolet-captiva-s599023/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/chevrolet-enjoy-s595824/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/tata-indicav2-s606823/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/tata-indicav2-s606617/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/marutisuzuki-estilo-2009-2014-s592745/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/toyota-etios-2013-2014-s605950/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/tata-indica-vista-2008-2011-s599001/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/opel-corsa-s591616/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/hyundai-i20-2008-2010-s596173/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/tata-indica-vista-2012-2014-s600753/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/fiat-punto-2009-2011-s606934/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/mitsubishi-pajero-s597849/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/fiat-linea20082014-s596079/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/tata-indicav2-s597390/
http://www.carwale.com/used/cars-in-trichy/mahindra-xylo-2009-2012-s603434/
```