# Trying to scrape dynamic data generated by google maps api on a website, but normal scraping returns blank

Tags: javascript, google-maps, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape jobs data from this [website](http://www.anyvan.com). One job page looks like [this](http://www.anyvan.com/view-listing/2178758). The static data can be easily scraped by scrapy but the dynamic data generated by google maps apis like the "Distance" and "Time" are giving me problem. I get "Distance Unknown" value for the distance field and blank value for the time field.

When I open the console in chrome, then in networks tab in the scripts section, I can see a java request ("DirectionsService.Route") that has been made to googles maps api and all the values that I need are there in a JSON format.

Is there a way in which I can use scrapy to get this json output generated by google maps api's ?

If not, then is there a way to program scrapy script to wait for the complete page load ( so that distance and time values load ) and then scrape these values ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that scrapy does not render javascript and the Distance and Time fields are both populated by javascript.

You have a few options.  You can use Splash (http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) made by the same folks as Scrapy or selenium/phantomjs.

[selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page) has lots of links/info in the answer.

As for JSON/scrapy, you can use the json library in python (import json) to load json into a python dictionary like:

```
   json_url = 'http://www.whatever.com/whatever.json'
   yield Request(json_url, callback=self.parse_json)

def parse_json(self, response):
   json_dict = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

If the URL you yielded returns JSON, the data will now be in a python dictionary called json_dict.