# scrapy - trying to get "next" url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy and trying to come up with a restrict_xpaths rule so the crawler will always go only to the next image.

I start with this image: 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/safaripartners/4838428819/in/photolist-qtC2e5-5iA4ZQ-8nydjx-zf1rvk-wvDaHE-8nBnhu-baArRv-36WzbG-2hLUaa-v6Mw1k-d33z5A-8nBniU-6jTfkT-6W6Sbu-5CtFsA-6RZZ5K-36WYuS-5DatmT-d5Qo1A-nMktKL-9wF1aF-hfuXhF-eLaQn5-5tR4Ri-prLcsi

and  my goal is to continuously scrape the next one.

I tried:

```
name = "FlickerSpider"
allowed_domains = ["flickr.com"]
start_urls = [
"https://www.flickr.com/photos/indymcduff/6632326011/in/photolist-9uQnYG-9SnqTY-qjXTHY-onEUN5-5d72ri-tgMKAY-8qaRQL-on6ZLu-bnMg2B-8AVUgV-b75pst/"
]
rules = (
    #crawl to next image
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'photos'),restrict_xpaths=('//class[@data="navigate-target navigate-next")]')) ,callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)
```

but I don't get any requests. 
Anyone has a suggestion of what rule should I be using?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your restrict_xpaths expression. Try

`restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="navigate-target navigate-next"]')`

It's always worth trying out your xpath using `scrapy shell` or using $x in Firebug for firefox. When there's an xpath problem like this in a rule it just silently fails.

**Update**

I should have given you this xpath

`restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="navigate-target navigate-next"]/@href')`

which works fine using the $x command in Firebug. As you said, it *doesn't* work with scrapy shell. It looks like that part of the page isn't part of the plain HTML but is generated at run-time. Unless you can find an alternative URL you might have to use something like Selenium which renders the page in a standard browser including dynamic content. Scrapy can then parse that HTML including the link you're after. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page).

Comment: You are right but it's only because I tried some things out.
Anyway- it still doesn't yield any request..
couldn't get it using scrapy shell as well.