# How to get link from onclick event using Scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I've been using Scrapy for getting content but I am having some trouble getting links from this particular site:[Taleo Site](https://cantire.taleo.net/careersection/2/joblist.ftl)

Clicking the title takes you to the job description. But the href is set to '#'.

And the onclick event is:

```
onclick="javascript:setEvent(event);requisition_openRequisitionDescription('requisitionListInterface','actOpenRequisitionDescription',_ftl_api.lstVal('requisitionListInterface', 'requisitionListInterface.listRequisition', 'requisitionListInterface.ID1380', this),_ftl_api.intVal('requisitionListInterface', 'requisitionListInterface.ID1384', this));return ftlUtil_followLink(this);
```

Also the link for all job descriptions is the same for all jobs. All of the description links are:

> https://cantire.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobdetail.ftl

I've been using scrapy for a while and would like to following the link and scrape the content. I'm just having trouble with this sort of setup where the href attribute is '#' and the link is created by JavaScript.

In the past I would do the following to get links and follow them, but in this case this doesn't work.

```
item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0]
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The browser sends a `POST` request instead of `GET` when you click on the job title. That's why the link is same only the `POST` request parameters differ with each job listing.

When you check the network console, you can see a `POST` request being send on this link `https://cantire.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobdetail.ftl` with various `formdata` (key-value pairs) . You can send a `POST` request with all the parameters using the `Request` module which will take you to the job description page.

The `POST` request will be something like:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url="https://cantire.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobdetail.ftl", method="POST", formdata={'key':'value'}, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend using Selenium + Scrapy for this. This way you can easily deal with both issues of clicking through and rendering dynamic content. [Helpful links here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)