# web scraping a webpage which has dynamic contents loaded via ajax

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Say I wish to scrape products on this [page](http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national/bread-bakery/fresh/bread#pageNumber=2&currentPageSize=20)(http://shop.coles.com.au/online/national/bread-bakery/fresh/bread#pageNumber=2&currentPageSize=20)

But the products is loaded from a `post` request. A lot of posts here suggest to simulate a request to get dynamic contents, but in my case the `Form Data` is unknown for me, i.e. `catalogId`, `categoryId`.

I'm wondering is it possible to get the `response` after the ajax call is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `catalogId` and other parameter values needed to make the POST request from the `form` with `id="search"`:

```
<form id="search" name="search" action="http://shop.coles.com.au/online/SearchDisplay?pageView=image&amp;catalogId=10576&amp;beginIndex=0&amp;langId=-1&amp;storeId=10601" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="storeId" value="10601" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_storeId_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="catalogId" value="10576" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_catalogId_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="langId" value="-1" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_langId_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="beginIndex" value="0" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_beginIndex_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="browseView" value="false" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_browseView_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    <input type="hidden" name="searchSource" value="Q" id="WC_CachedHeaderDisplay_FormInput_searchSource_In_CatalogSearchForm_1">
    ...
</form>
```

Use the [`FormRequest`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) to submit this form.

---

> I'm wondering is it possible to get the response after the ajax call is finished?

Scrapy is not a browser - it does not make additional AJAX requests to load the page and there is nothing built-in to execute JavaScript. You may look into using a real browser and solve it on a higher level - look into [`selenium` package](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). There is also the related [`scrapy-splash`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) project.

See also:

- [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)