# Execute inline JavaScript in Scrapy response

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I am trying to log into a website with Scrapy, but the response received is an HTML document containing only inline JavaScript. The JS redirects to the page I want to scrape data from. But Scrapy does not execute the JS and therefore doesn't route to the page I want it to.

I use the following code to submit the login form required:

```
    def parse(self, response):
      request_id =   response.css('input[name="request_id"]::attr(value)').extract_first()
      data = {
          'userid_placeholder': self.login_user,
          'foilautofill': '',
          'password': self.login_pass,
          'request_id': request_id,
          'username': self.login_user[1:]
      }
      yield   scrapy.FormRequest(url='https://www1.up.ac.za/oam/server/auth_cred_submit',   formdata=data,
                               callback=self.print_p)
```

The print_p callback function is as follows:

```
def print_p(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

I have looked at scrapy-splash but I could not find a way to execute the JS in the response with scrapy-splash.

Comment: have you tried to manually go to the page the JS redirections bring you to ? (that's to say, scrap an url in `print_p` and yield a request to this page)

Comment: @Pablo The JS builds a url which it then redirects to.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) as a rendering service. Personally, I found it more reliable than Selenium. Using [scripts](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html), you can instruct it to interact with the page.

Answer (score 2):

Probably selenium can help you pass this JS.

If you haven't checked it yet you can use some examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page). If you'll have luck to reach it then you can get page url with:

```
self.driver.current_url
```

And scrape it after.