# Scraping <a href> tags in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble scraping specific content from the following webpage.

http://www.librarything.com/search.php?search=The+Fellowship+of+the+Ring

The data that I need is the 'work' number of the first book: http://prntscr.com/hfkiku

I've tried using Beautiful Soup and Selenium and have not been able to find a way to get that information.

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: Code attached.

```
def getWebpage(bookName):
    #website = 'http://www.librarything.com/title/' + bookName
    website = 'http://www.librarything.com/search.php?search=The+Fellowship+of+the+Ring'
    #print(website)

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    request = http.request('GET', website)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.data)

    websiteP = soup.prettify()

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(website)

    delay = 5

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'p.item')))
        print('Page is Ready!')
        for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.item'):
            print(element.text)
    except TimeoutException:
        print('couldnt load page')
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

html result:

```
Page is Ready!
The Fellowship of the Ring: Being the First Part of The Lord of the Rings by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring [2001 film] by Peter Jackson
The Fellowship of the Ring
The Fellowship of the Ring Journeybook by Matthew Ward
The Fellowship of the ring by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Fellowship of the Ring by J. R. R.
The Fellowship of the Ring Sourcebook by decipherrpg
The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack by Howard Shore
The Fellowship of the Ring by Coleman Charlton
The Fellowship of the Ring {American dramatization} by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Fellowship of the Ring by aa
The Fellowship of the Ring Insiders' Guide (The Lord of the Rings Movie Tie-In) by Brian Sibley
The Lord of the Rings {complete} by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Hobbit and The Lord of the Rings by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Fellowship of the Ring by John Ronald Reuel Tolkien; Alan Lee
J.R.R. Tolkien Reads and Sings The Hobbit and The Fellowship of the Ring by J.R.R. Tolkien
The Fellowship of the Ring - Part One - Ballantine
The Fellowship of the Ring {unspecified}
The Fellowship Of The Ring Isbn 0261102311
The Fellowship of the Ring [Videorecording]
The Fellowship of the Ring Sourcebook (The Lord of the Rings Roleplaying Game) by Decipher RPG
The Fellowship of the Ring Book One
The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring: Piano, Vocal, and Chords by Howard Shore
```

Tried changing the code around a bit but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Yes, BeautifulSoup is the tool you'll need to accomplish this. There are the official docs and a lot of tutorials that explain how to use it. Here we aren't writing tutorials for you, nor do we link people to them or other off-site resources. So, you should just google something like "BeautifulSoup tutorial", and you'll get a lot of useful information. The first thing you'll need to learn is how to actually retrieve the pages of the site. This isn't hard to do, and again, there are plenty of tutorials about this out there. Try searching for "Python `requests`".

Comment: BTW, it can be done by Selenium also.

Comment: @ForceBru
I have looked at multiple tutorials for Beautiful Soup and nothing worked. This is the approach that I've used: http://prntscr.com/hfl5yi

The problem is that the tags with the work number don't appear when I print out the html of the page. I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov

I've tried using Selenium too as shown here http://prntscr.com/hfl6zn but again, I can't locate the element that I need.

Comment: Can you update the Question with your code trial & relevant HTML?

Comment: @Univold, where is your traceback (full error message)? HTML?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov edited with code and result attached

Comment: @DebanjanB edited with code and result attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the occasions that driver.page_source does not show the expected HTML but if you select the innerHTML of the body tag you get what you are expecting.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "http://www.librarything.com/search.php?search=The+Fellowship+of+the+Ring"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

#This next line does not show the expected html.
# print (driver.page_source)

# But this finds it.
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute('innerHTML')
driver .quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, "html.parser")
ps = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "item"})
for p in ps:
    print (p.find("a")['href'].split('/')[2])
```

Outputs:

```
3203347
1354927
20066223
4819791
7170476
...
```

P.S. Welcome to StackOverflow a word of advice, please post your code in your questions they will be better received and it makes it easier for other people to run the code than if you post it in an screenshot image which can't be easily copied to a IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the introduction, new to StackOverflow.

Just had a question though. Is there any faster alternative to this method? I'm basically making a rudimentary book recommendation system so I'm going to need the numbers for lots of different books which, I'd imagine, would take a long time to do using this method.

Comment: Yes there is but it s a bit more programming: use Scrapy https://scrapy.org/  to fetch all book on the website with either selenium or Scrapy & JavaScript integration through Splash https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page for starters. If this answer answered your original question don't forget to accept it.