# Scrapy with selenium duplicate requests?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am just confused behind the logic of requesting single page twice when scrapy is used with selenium webdriver. In most of cases I see following code in `parse` function e.g

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.selenium.get(response.url)
    # do some other stuff
    self.selenium.close()
```

So my question is , when `parse` function gets the response, scrapy has already made an http request to page ? and in the function body we are making same request using selenium driver ? If my assumption is true 
how we can avoid this ? If not what is in the response arugment passed?

Some examples [1](https://github.com/matheenpasha/scrapy-with-selenium/blob/master/Demo/Demo/spiders/demo_spider.py), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page#17979285)

Comment: you can use `Selenium` without `scrapy` to get data from page so `scrapy` seems usless in this example. But `scrapy` gives other useful elements like Pipelines to clear data, saving in csv, json, xml, filtering duplicated urls, downloading files/images, etc.

Comment: BTW: based on [image in documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) you should have to replace "downloader" to use only Selenium - and this can be a problem.

Comment: yes I see its trying to place multiple requests asynchronously