# Avoid to be detected during scrape

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the website of lacentrale.fr thanks to scrapy, but even if I rotate my users agent and IP address (thanks to TOR), the web site detect my robot and send me false values.
Please can you check my code used in middlwares and setting and tell me if something went wrong.

code in middlewares :

```
from tutorial.settings import * #USER_AGENT_LIST
import random

from stem.control import Controller
from toripchanger import TorIpChanger
from stem import Signal

class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    ua = random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)
    if ua:
        request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)


def _set_new_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password='')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

ip_changer = TorIpChanger(reuse_threshold=10)
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    _requests_count = 0

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    self._requests_count += 1
    if self._requests_count > 10:
        self._requests_count = 0
        ip_changer.get_new_ip()

        print("New Tor connection processed")

    request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
    spider.log('Proxy : %s' % request.meta['proxy'])
```

Code used in settings :

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'


ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True


DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'tutorial.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware':None, # to avoid the raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file' exceptions.IOError: Not a gzipped file
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'tutorial.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100
    }



USER_AGENT_LIST=[

    {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1469.0 Safari/537.36'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1469.0 Safari/537.36'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'},
    {
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'},
    {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0'},
    {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
    ]
```

EDIT II

it's seems that tor use the same ip each time and there is not rotation on the ip address. I don't know what I can change in my middlwares file to resolve this !!
please any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be detected on several factors, including whether your scraper downloads/runs the javascript files. If that's the case, you may need to use a tool like selenium in conjunction with Python/Scrapy to further pretend like a normal human user.

This stackoverflow post offers some help in getting started:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979285/9693088

I don't think I can offer much guidance in what may be going wrong with your TOR set up