# Scrapy with multiple Selenium instances (parallel)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I need to scrape many urls with `Selenium` and `Scrapy`. To speed up whole process, I'm trying to create a bunch of shared `Selenium` instances. My idea is to have a set of parallel `Selenium` instances available to any `Request` if needed and `released` if done.

I tried to create a `Middleware` but the problem is that `Middleware` is sequential (I see all drivers (I call it browsers) loading urls and it seems to be sequential). I want all drivers work parallel.

```
class ScrapySpiderDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    BROWSERS_COUNT = 10

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.free_browsers = set(
            [webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=BASE_DIR + '/chromedriver') for x in range(self.BROWSERS_COUNT)])

    def get_free_browser(self):
        while True:
            try:
                return self.free_browsers.pop()
            except KeyError:
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def release_browser(self, browser):
        self.free_browsers.add(browser)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        browser = self.get_free_browser()

        browser.get(request.url)

        body = str.encode(browser.page_source)
        self.release_browser(browser)

        # Expose the driver via the "meta" attribute
        request.meta.update({'browser': browser})

        return HtmlResponse(
            browser.current_url,
            body=body,
            encoding='utf-8',
            request=request
        )
```

I don't like solutions where you do:

```
driver.get(response.url)
```

in `parse` method because it causes redundant requests. Every url is being requested two times which I need to avoid.

For example this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979285/2607447

Do you know what to do?

Comment: Have you looked into Splash? It's a microservice which performs function you are looking for - it has N number of workers that act as middlemen and render your requests in webtkit. https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash

Comment: @Granitosaurus Thank you, I'm trying to make it work and it works but I have one little problem. I'm afraid lua_script splash:go performs new request. I've posted a new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327258/scrapy-splash-does-splashgourl-in-lua-script-perform-get-request-again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look towards scrapy + docker. you can run many instances at once

Answer (score 0):

As @Granitosaurus suggested, Splash is a good choice. I personally used [Scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) - `Scrapy` takes care of parallel processing and `Splash` takes care of website rendering including `JavaScript` execution.