# Scrapy-splash - does splash:go(url) in lua_script perform GET request again?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm new to `Scrapy-splash` and I'm trying to scrape a lazy `datatable` which is a table with AJAX pagination.

So I need to load the website, wait until `JS` is executed, get html of the table and then click on the "Next" button on pagination.

My approach works but I'm afraid I'm requesting the website two times.

First time when I yield the `SplashRequest` and then when `lua_script` is executed.

Is it true? If yes, how to make it perform request just once?

```
class JSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'js_spider'
    script = """
    function main(splash, args)
        splash:go(args.url)
        splash:wait(0.5)
        local page_one = splash:evaljs("$('#example').html()")
        splash:evaljs("$('#example_next').click()")
        splash:wait(2)
        local page_two = splash:evaljs("$('#example').html()")
        return {page_one=page_one,page_two=page_two}
    end"""

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f"""https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html"""
        yield SplashRequest(url, endpoint='execute',callback=self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5,'lua_source':self.script,'url':url})

    def parse(self, response):
        # assert isinstance(response, SplashTextResponse)
        page_one = response.data.get('page_one',None)
        page_one_root = etree.fromstring(page_one, HTMLParser())
        page_two = response.data.get('page_two',None)
        page_two_root = etree.fromstring(page_one, HTMLParser())
```

**EDIT**

Also I would like to wait until `AJAX` is performed better way than just `splash:wait(2)`. Is it possible to somehow wait until the table changed? Ideally with some timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua script is very literal - if you have 1 `splash:go` then one request is made by 1 splash worker.
Your crawler is fine here.

To pointlessly nit pick though: your spider connects to a worker via http so *in theory* two requests are being made: 1st to splash service and 2nd to target by splash worker.