# Share web session between Scrapy and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I want to create a process that uses selenium and scrapy. I want to click a button with selenium and after pass the html page to scrapy, but I needed to login a site with selenium. If I just pass the url, scrapy will do nothing.
Can I 'share' the web session?

Comment: Why don't you use scrapy directly to login?

Comment: This is possible but I agree with the above commenter that using only Scrapy would make the most sense to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page

However, that question/answer has an example which combines their uses.

Could you upload any attempts you have made to write code that solves this?