# How to **prevent** Scrapy Request from downloading the request?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, python-requests, ngrep

I am making a Selenium-based spider for dynamic websites. But I want to stay within the Scrapy framework as this spider is part of a bigger project which utilizes all the spiders using the same workflow/commands.

The easiest thing to do is, to pass the requests from `start_requests()` to `parse()` and do all the Selenium stuff within `parse()`.

However, this way, I will be making double requests to the website - once by Scrapy, and once by Selenium.

What I want is, to pass only the url to Selenium in `parse()`, download it, and parse further:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield from self.parse(url)
```

It's the first thing that comes to mind, but seems Scrapy has limitations that `start_requests()` must yield eventually a `Request` type of object. And if I do so, I am getting errors (can specify them upon request).

So I came up with another idea: to use the original `start_requests()`, because a `Request` object is not supposed to download the page itself, and disable the download middleware which does so. However, even when disabling all middlewares:

```
custom_settings = {
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
    },
    'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
    },
    'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {
    },
}
```

when I check the outgoing requests with `ngrep`, I can see that still, Scrapy is also downloading the remote url apart from Selenium, despite the custom settings which should have cut off the Downloader.

How do I download the urls only once via Selenium in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)