# I'm trying to scrape Startup-india website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I know it's not a error but I'm not understanding how to scrape startup india website, I'm trying to click some website given in startup India but I can't click on them because scrapy can't click on websites and whatever information I'm having can only be scraped by pressing that link.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import os

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.startupindia.gov.in/content/sih/en/search.html?industries=sih:industry/advertising&states=sih:location/india/andhra-pradesh&stages=Prototype&roles=Startup&page=0']

    def __init__(self):
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/RAJ/PycharmProjects/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/WebCrawler/spiders/chromedriver.exe")
        self.profile = []

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="persona-results"]/div[1]/div/a/div[1]')

            try:
                next.click()

                # get the data and write it to scrapy items
            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

By the way, my end goal is to go get all the profile details but I don't know-how
(PS: This is the first time me doing web scraping)

Comment: If only showing me the code to I guess click on website would be great.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page

Comment: You cannot click by Scrapy itself, instead you can fetch the HREF somehow. Put the link and your try in your question.

Comment: I'm using selenium spiders for this though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something similar to the tutorial on Scrapy documentation as below. In general, you can try to refer to the `#follow links to author pages` , right click and inspect the place to "click" to get the css/xpath on your desired webpage.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

Alternatively, feel free to share what you have.
Hope this helps!

```
import scrapy


    class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'author'

        start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

        def parse(self, response):
            # follow links to author pages
            for href in response.css('.author + a::attr(href)'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse_author)

            # follow pagination links
            for href in response.css('li.next a::attr(href)'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

        def parse_author(self, response):
            def extract_with_css(query):
                return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()

            yield {
                'name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
                'birthdate': extract_with_css('.author-born-date::text'),
                'bio': extract_with_css('.author-description::text'),
            }
```