# What are the risks of overriding a scrapy.spider's __init__ method?

Tags: python, scrapy

In some stack overflow questions I've seen accepted answers where the `__init__` method of the scrapy.spider superclass is overriden by the user defined spider. For example: [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page).

My question is, what are the risks of doing so? The `__init__` of the super class looks like this:

```
class Spider(object_ref):
    """Base class for scrapy spiders. All spiders must inherit from this
    class.
    """

    name = None
    custom_settings = None

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        if name is not None:
            self.name = name
        elif not getattr(self, 'name', None):
            raise ValueError("%s must have a name" % type(self).__name__)
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        if not hasattr(self, 'start_urls'):
            self.start_urls = []
```

So, if I were to define an `__init__` in my spider that inherits from this class and didn't include a call to the superclass `__init__` would I be breaking scrapy functionality? How to mitigate that risk? Call the super's `__init__` in my spider? Looking for best practices for scrapy and also a better understanding of `__init__` calls in the context of class inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None if you use `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Anything else is a risk. You are copying code from the `__init__` method of `Spider` in a specific Scrapy version, hence the only safe upgrade path involves checking how the `Spider.__init__` implementation changes in new Scrapy versions and applying the changes to your custom implementation as you upgrade Scrapy.

If you can implement the same logic keeping a call to `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, that would be best.

If not, looking for alternative implementations, or opening a feature request so that Scrapy can accommodate your use case in an upgrade-safe way, would be better long-term solutions.

Comment: So using `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` preserves the superclass funcitonality. If I also needed to pass arguments to the spider-specific `__init__` it's unclear to me how python will know which arguments go where. To help me understand could you be more explicit about how both `__init__` methods work when they're both present?

Comment: if you use `__init__(*args, *, name=None, **kwargs)` in your spider signature, `name` will only be accepted as a keyword-only parameter (avoiding issues in the unlikely scenario that the parent class introduces new positional arguments), and `name` would not be included in `kwargs`, hence it would not be passed to the parent spider class when using `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`. Mind that if `name` is also used by the parent spider class, you would be preventing the parent spider class from getting that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the `Spider.__init__`, it only takes care of `self.name` and `self.start_urls`. If you handle these by yourself in class attributes just like the example answer you mentioned, you can completely skip the init method altogether and it would still work just fine.

In python, init is just a function that gets called for custom initialization and if you don't define it, it's equivalent to doing `def __init__(self): pass`.

`super().__init__` is good to have for cooperative inheritance where you have multiple base classes. For spider, it's mostly unrelated, unless you are writing a ton of spiders that are related and actually need cooperative inheritance.

lt;dr : you can skip it altogether. Just make sure you define `name` and `start_urls` in either your init or in class attributes

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. Thanks.

In order to preserve the functionality of a super class' `__init__` while also extending the functionality in your custom subclass you'd do this.

In the subclass `__init__` method you'd add you're custom keyword args then end by passing `*args, **kwargs`. Then explicitly call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` in the body of the `__init__`. Like this:

```
class SubClass(SuperClass)
    def __init__(self, custom_1, custom_2, *args, **kwargs):

        # Your code here that handles custom args

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The custom arguments will be handled by your custom code then `*args, **kwargs` will be consumed by the super class' `__init__`. Careful that you get the order of the `__init__` calls right if they're dependent on each other.

A perfect example of this whole thing is the SeleniumRequest in [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) middleware.