# Web Scraping using Scrapy

Tags: python, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am scraping the Flipcart website and I want to extract the image URL from the website. [This is the link to the website](https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen).

```
import scrapy
from ..items import FlipcartItem
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='quotes'
    start_urls=[
        'https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen'
        ]
    def parse(self,response):
        items=FlipcartItem()
        image_url=response.css('._2r_T1I img::attr(src)').extract()
        #product_page_url=response.css('').extract()
        items['image_url']=image_url
        #items['product_page']=title
        yield items
```

This is the code I have written and while running the code I am getting the empty list.Like image_url ["","",""].Can anyone please
suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This site is using javascript to load images that scrapy won't access. You need to use
[selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract image data. Here i use scrapy Selector to extract image data with selenium. You may use scrapy with selenium if you want follow this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page) or [scrapy splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
browser.get(url="https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen")

page = browser.page_source
image_data = Selector(text=page)
image_data = image_data.css('img._2r_T1I::attr(src)').extract()
# print(image_data.xpath('//div[@class="CXW8mj _21_khk"]/img/@src').get())

print(image_data)
```

If you need to install selenium, please follow this [url](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing this line:

```
image_url=response.css('._2r_T1I img::attr(src)').extract()
```

To this,

```
image_urls=response.css('img._2r_T1I').xpath('@src').getall()
```

Also you should be aware that your "image_url" is going to be an array even if there's only  one item, as that's what scrapy returns. You may want to iterate over the results and create a new `FlipcartItem` for each one, or if you only expect one result you may want to pull it out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried Doing This :

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='quotes'
    start_urls=[
        'https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen'
        ]
    def parse(self,response):
        raw_image_urls=response.css('img._2r_T1I').xpath('@src').getall()
        clean_image_urls=[]
        for img_url in raw_image_urls:
            clean_image_urls.append(response.urljoin(img_url))
        yield{
        'image_urls':clean_image_urls
        }
```

But getting the URL of the main page.Not image url.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript generated content site. Use "View page source" and you can see that the image **src** is empty. Nothings wrong with the code. Just use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [Scrapy Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) they load all the javascripts for you so you can scraped the data.